# How to run a script using SSH

Tags: ssh

Complete beginner question...

Let's say I have SSH access to my website. And, I have a file:

mywebsite.com/foo/my_script.php

How can I use SSH to run my_script.php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ssh username@mywebsite.com "/usr/bin/php /path/to/my_script.php"
```

Just make sure that the user you use to login is the user you want to run the script as.

Also make sure that you actually have /usr/bin/php installed. Running a PHP script from the command line isn't the same as starting it from say Apache.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it right in one line (like your example). I made it work by entering separate commands. First, login to ssh. Second "ls" and "cd" a few times to get to the file. Finally, run the file with "php my_script.php"

Comment: Perhaps you don't have PHP cli installed as /usr/bin/php. What does "which php", on the server, tell you?

Answer (score 0):

You can also make the PHP file like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    echo 'Hello world';
?>
```

and then just type

```
/path/to/my_script.php
```

in SSH and it will work also